# tikz terminal at gnuplot

Tags: latex, gnuplot, tikz

I'm trying to build a graph with gnuplot in LaTeX document (nic.tex)

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}



\begin{document}
    \begin{gnuplot}[terminal = tikz]
        plot sin(x)
    \end{gnuplot}
\end{document}
```

but get an error

```
Opening gnuplot stream ./nic-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot (nic-gnuplottex-fig1.tex

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/gnuplot' and I am going t
o ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.1 \begin{tikzpicture}[gnuplot]
```

I use Windows 10, MiKTeX 2.9, gnuplot version 5.4

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved. It was necessary to create a style file in gnuplot and use it in LaTeX document.